# How to stop an index of Amazon Elasticsearch service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm trying to restore a snapshot saved on S3. The snapshot is an Amazon Elasticsearch service cluster from my another Amazon ES domain.

While trying to restore that on a new Amazon ES domain, it gives an error:

**"Cannot restore because index [.kibana] is open".**

So I tried to close it by running: POST /my_index/_close

But it seems Amazon not allows close of index as it was giving below error:

**.kibana/_close is not allowed by Amazon Elasticsearch service.**

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to restore the snapshot by taking a partial snapshot without kibana and then restoring it on that different ES domain.